# Upsampling using 3d transpose convolutions in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, convolution

I define a 3D transpose convolution in Tensorflow as follows:

```
def weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean = 0.0, stddev=0.1))

def biases(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(value = 0.1, shape = shape))

def trans_conv3d(x, W, output_shape, strides, padding):
    return tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(x, W, output_shape, strides, padding)

def transconv3d_layer(x, shape, out_shape, strides, padding):
   # shape: [depth, height, width, output_channels, in_channels].
   # output_shape: [batch, depth, height, width, output_channels]
    W = weights(shape)
    b = biases([shape[4]]) 
    return tf.nn.elu(trans_conv3d(x, W, out_shape, strides, padding) + b)
```

Suppose I have a 4D tensor `x` from a previous layer with shape `[2, 1, 1, 1, 10]` where `batch = 2`, `depth = 1`, `height = 1`, `width = 1`, and `in_channels = 10` as set out [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d_transpose).

**How would I use `transconv3d_layer` to upsample `x`, *over a sequence of layers*, to have a final shape such as `[2, 100, 100, 100, 10]` or something similar?** It is not clear to me how to follow the shape of my tensor through transpose layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can use it:

```
input = tf.random_normal(shape=[2, 1, 1, 1, 10])
deconv1 = transconv3d_layer(input,
                            shape=[2, 3, 3, 10, 10],
                            out_shape=[2, 50, 50, 50, 10],
                            strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                            padding='SAME')
deconv2 = transconv3d_layer(deconv1,
                            shape=[2, 3, 3, 10, 10],
                            out_shape=[2, 100, 100, 100, 10],
                            strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                            padding='SAME')
# deconv3 ...

print(deconv1)  # Tensor("Elu:0", shape=(2, 50, 50, 50, 10), dtype=float32)
print(deconv2)  # Tensor("Elu_1:0", shape=(2, 100, 100, 100, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Basically, you should specify each `out_shape` to be the one you'd like to upsample to: `(2, 50, 50, 50, 10)`, `(2, 100, 100, 100, 10)`, ...

Just for clarity, here's what the dimensions in different tensors above mean:

```
input shape:  [batch, depth, height, width, in_channels]
filter shape: [depth, height, width, output_channels, in_channels]
output shape: [batch, depth, height, width, output_channels]
```

Comment: Thank-you. But what if I wanted to get to the shape [2, 100, 100, 100, 10] over a **series of transpose convolutional layers**, one after the other?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this design. Normally the layer takes an input from the previous layer, so you'll have a DECONV - DECONV ... pattern. Is this what you mean? Or do you mean multiple DECONV layers from the same input?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the former or the latter of your previous statement, but it would look like this:

`x = tf.random_normal(shape=[2, 1, 1, 1, 10])`

`transconv1 = transconv3d_layer(x, shape=s1, out_shape=o1, strides=st1, padding=pd1)`

`transconv2 = transconv3d_layer(transconv1, shape=s2, out_shape=o2, strides=st2, padding=pd2)`

Where the shape of transconv2 would be `[2, 100, 100, 100, 10]`

Comment: That makes more sense. But note that after the first conv layer, the shape is already `[2, 100, 100, 100, 10]`.  So upsampling to *the same* shape is meaningless. You should apply a normal convolution if you'd like

Comment: But what if I wanted to use several trans convolutional layers to reach the final shape of `[2, 100, 100, 100 10]`, so the **upsampling was gradual** and not in one go? For example `transconv1` might have a shape `[2, 50, 50, 50, 10]` and then `transconv2` would have shape `[2, 100, 100, 100, 10]` as it is the final layer.

Comment: Hm, note that it's the first time you mention the shape `[2, 50, 50, 50, 100]`. Finally, I understand your question. The solution is absolutely the same - call the `transconv3d_layer` 2 or more times with `out_shape`s you want.